# Extract records from data.table with different time periods

Tags: r

I have a data.table which looks like this:

```
Date         ID     Institution
2015-08-01   55     12
2015-08-02   55     13
2015-08-03   55     12
```

Basically, what I want is to extract certain records for each ID where they enter one institution, exit that institution, and then return to the first institution for the first institution they entered. That is, in the example above, I would like to get the following:

```
Date         ID     Institution
2015-08-01   55     12
2015-08-03   55     12
```

My data set is dynamic, so I'm hoping to write a function to extract those filtered records for those unique cases. Currently I've just manually extracted those records and I've hardcoded a solution, but this won't suffice moving forward. Any input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: As far as automating the extraction process, I have not come up with a solution yet. Once I extract the records I know how to deal with them, it's just the extraction that is causing me problems.

Comment: Spend some time trying to work out a solution. Your computer isn't going to blow up if you don't get it right on the first try.

Comment: I am not shure, whether I understood the question. Apparently, you can divide the original data set into smaller ones, one for each ID. Then you look for each institution that appears at least twice with at least one different institution in between? Is that the problem or do you mind explaining the problem in more detail?

Comment: @Bernhard yes, that is the problem.

Comment: So once you isolated each ID you could compute the Date ranks for each institution. In the example above, Institution 12 has the ranks `c(1, 3)`. 12 is one of the answers, as `diff(c(1, 3))` contains values that are different from one, or as you might put it in R: `any(as.integer(diff(c(1, 3)) - 1) > 0)`. Institution 13 has only rank 2. So `any(as.integer(diff(c(2))-1)>0)`. Does that help?

Comment: That is generally what I have in mind. I will give it a shot, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score -1):

A somewhat convoluted answer, I'm still not expert with `dplyr`:
The example data:

```
df=data.frame(Date=as.Date(c(25,27,30,12,13,14,15,17,25),origin="2015-05-05"),
              ID=c(55,55,55,33,33,33,65,65,65),
              Institution=c(12,13,12,12,12,12,13,13,12))
        Date ID Institution
1 2015-05-30 55          12
2 2015-06-01 55          13
3 2015-06-04 55          12
4 2015-05-17 33          12
5 2015-05-18 33          12
6 2015-05-19 33          12
7 2015-05-20 65          13
8 2015-05-22 65          13
9 2015-05-30 65          12
```

Using the package `dplyr`to create a tibble that contains the ID for which we have 2 (can be modified) different Institution.
  `library(dplyr)
check=df%>%group_by(ID)%>%summarise(visited=n_distinct(Institution))%>%filter(visited==2)`
We then use this tibble to retrieve the Date, ID and Institution for these ones:

```
df[df$ID%in%check$ID,]%>%distinct(ID,Institution,.keep_all=T)
        Date ID Institution
1 2015-05-30 55          12
2 2015-06-01 55          13
3 2015-05-20 65          13
4 2015-05-30 65          12
```

You can probably improve upon this and do it in a single line of code.